# Why should you use a POST request to access GraphQL endpoints using fetch or axios?

Tags: graphql

Is there a reason why the request to GraphQL endpoints through Javascript libraries like fetch or axios is passed as a POST request?

Technically we are just getting data from the server, so it must be a GET request. But in all the examples for axios and fetch, I see that they are passed as post requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Technically we are just getting data from the server, so it must be a GET request.

Well that's only the case when you run a `query`, not when you run a `mutation`.

But more importantly, you're not just getting data from the server, you're also sending data to the server: the query document and optionally some variables and an operation name. Since [`GET` requests ought not to have a body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/1048572), `POST` was chosen.

That said, [this is just a convention](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) adopted by most endpoints, the GraphQL spec does not actually require it but allows any transport. You could also send the query document in a header, you could send it as part of the URL, you could send only the name of a predefined query to the server, then you could easily [use `GET` requests](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#get-request) - but beware of size limits and impact of caching.